# Thank you to the moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators

I was surprised and disappointed to catch up on the events that has led to the dismissal and resignation of three of our moderators.

I think that they, and all other moderators on The Workplace, past and present, should be thanked for the time and effort they've all put in guiding our community over the years. Especially for their efforts to make the site more inclusive and welcoming to newcomers.

The Workplace will miss Monica, Jane, Mister Positive and Snow's contributions as moderators. I hope we will not also be missing your contributions as members of the our community.

Comment: And let's hope there are no others to follow! Though I am of course supportive of those that decide to do so.

Comment: What I really hope is that this whole situation is sorted out and that SE *strongly* reconsiders the steps they have been taking lately unless they want to ruin this Network.

Comment: @DarkCygnus I fear that is already too late. Trust takes years to build and seconds to break.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the time and effort.... good luck with your journeys

Comment: @JaneS _"Trust takes years to build and seconds to break"_ - how true! Though I just recently joined I want to thank you, Snow, Monica for all the hard work you put in over the years and wish that you'll now have plenty of delightful moments, interactions and joy during the times which are now not anymore occupied by moderating. A big shout out to all of you!

Comment: I took the liberty to edit to add Mister Positive to the "people we will miss" list

Comment: @LP154 Thanks - I was a little remiss in not doing that myself

Comment: Thank you.  Re your last sentence and speaking only for myself: if they don't right this wrong, I'm done here.  We all have our limits to the amount of bullying, lying, and personal attacks we can endure, and I've reached mine.  It was good while it lasted.  Best wishes to The Workplace.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks friends. I hope you all stick around to contribute to The Workplace in a non-moderator role.

But if not, I wish you all well in whatever new forums you decide to use your talents.

Comment: Thanks Joe, that's very much appreciated.  I think we're all waiting to see what the official response is and to what extent they'll value the work we put into the sites.